# How to replace a parameterized type with a more specific one

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

**Consider the following setup:**

We have an interface `SuperType` which is parameterized like this:

```
public interface SuperType<V> {
}
```

`SuperType` supports method chaining. Hence it defines another type parameter which captures the concrete implementing subtype returned by each method like this:

```
public interface SuperType<V, S extends SuperType<V, S>> {

    public S doSomething();
}
```

Let's consider an implementation of `SuperType<V, S extends SuperType<V, S>>`:

```
public class SubType<V> implements SuperType<V, SubType<V>> {

    private final V value;

    public SubType(V value) { this.value = value; }

    public SubType<V> doSomething() { return this; }
}
```

Someone instantiates `SubType<V>` using for example strings but provides `Object` for the type parameter `V`:

```
Object s = "Java Generics";
SubType<Object> x = new SubType<>(s);
```

Now we want to define another method for `SuperType<V, S extends SuperType<V, S>>` which takes a more specific type parameter of `V` and returns the same implementation type `S` but now parameterized with `W extends V`:

```
public interface SuperType<V, S extends SuperType<V, S>> {

    public S doSomething();

    public <W extends V, T extends SuperType<W, T>> T doMoreSpecific(Class<W> typeToken);
}
```

This new interface definition is intended to support:

```
Object s = "Java Generics";
SubType<Object> x = new SubType<>(s);
SubType<String> y = x.doMoreSpecific(String.class);
```

Here I struggle to implement `SubType<V>`. What I want to provide as an implementation is:

```
public class SubType<V> implements SuperType<V, SubType<V>> {

    private final V value;

    public SubType(V value) { this.value = value; }

    public SubType<V> doSomething() { return this; };

    public <W extends V> SubType<W> doMoreSpecific(Class<W> typeToken) {
        return new SubType<>((W) value);
    }
}
```

**My Question is:**

How should I define the signature for the method `doMoreSpecific()` in the type `SuperType<V, S extends SuperType<V, S>>` so that the implementation provided by
`SubType<V> implements SuperType<V, SubType<V>>` is acceptable?

Or otherwise, which implementation and interface method definition would do the trick?

Or else, why can't we do this in Java?

Comment: just a commnet, in an interface, all methods are abstract, so the explicit definition is redundant

Comment: `S extends <V, S>` is not valid syntax which makes your question difficult to understand...

Comment: I hope I fixed the syntax errors. I was to lazy to define all the types in my IDE :). Sorry.

Comment: @sharonbn True. They are also `public`. I write neither `public` nor `abstract` for interface methods.

Comment: @Harmlezz My IDE does not agree with the  `S extends<V, S>` part.

Comment: @ Chop: hope I fixed everything in the question. You may edit my post as well, if you find more syntax errors. I would appreciate it :)

Comment: @Harmlezz You are about to make your code unreadable and too complex.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: My IDE generated `public <W extends V, T extends SuperType<W, T>> T doMoreSpecific(Class<W> typeToken) {` but I can't seem to get the type for `T` right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following signature:

```
<W extends V> SuperType<W, ?> doMoreSpecific(Class<W> typeToken);
```

There might be some unsafe cases though that I have not been able to find yet, any criticism is welcome!

Comment: Your solution does the trick but I am not able to implement the method in an abstract class or as a default method. If I do that, I will lose the type of the concrete implementation, which may implement even more interfaces. I missed to mention that as well in my question but I tried to avoid to much details. Nevertheless, if no better solution comes up, I will take your solution.

Comment: @Harmlezz - you can keep old definition as `doMoreSpecific0`; and `doMoreSpecific` simply invokes `doMoreSpecific`; the inference seems working out here to get `T`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what your code suggests you want, you have a typed *method*: `W` is inferred from the parameter type, but the parameter type is known only at the call site. ie there isn't *one* version of the method `doMoreSpecific()` that can be specified in the interface `SuperType` (that must be implemented).

The closest you could get is to make `W` a generic type parameter of `SuperType`, but then your implementation would work for exactly one class `W`, which would be the typeToken redundant, which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: I had a discussion with a coworker about my problem and he told me, that what I like to have is not available in _Java_ but in _Scala_: a type constructor. In my opinion the problem I face is that I am not able to extract the _raw type_ from the parametrized type to formulate the new type which to return. For example if I could extract the raw type from `S`, lets say `raw:S` than I could define the signature as follows: `public <W extends V> raw:S extends SuperType<W, raw:S> doMoreSpecific(Class<W> typeToken);` Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your exact intention is behind `doMoreSpecific`, but if it is just casting from `SubType<Object>` to `SubType<String>` you could do the following (although this is not very good practice...):

```
Object s = "Java Generics";
SubType<Object> x = new SubType<>(s);
SubType<String> y = (SubType<String>) (SubType<?>) x;
```

Note 1: This will still give a Warning.

Note 2: This cast will even work if `s` is not of Type `String`! But you will then get a ClassCastException when calling `y.doSomething()`. (Which you would get in your example for that case, too).

For example: The following piece of (ugly) code would work, too (except for the lines highlighted):

```
    ArrayList<?> lo = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ArrayList<Integer> li = (ArrayList<Integer>) lo;
    ArrayList<String> ls = (ArrayList<String>) lo;

    li.add(5);
    ls.add("five");

    System.out.println(lo);        // prints "[5, five]"

    System.out.println(li.get(0)); // prints "5"
    System.out.println(li.get(1)); // ClassCastException

    System.out.println(ls.get(0)); // ClassCastException
    System.out.println(ls.get(1)); // prints "five"
```

Note 3: This perfectly shows how generics in fact work: All they do is automatically insert casts at the required positions for you.